# Laravel Show particular data from array of objects

Tags: laravel-8

I have a field called **"menuIds"** in "menu-permissions" table where the data looks like this--

```
[{"id":1,"menuName":"service","code":"1"},
{"id":2,"menuName":"food","code":"3"},
{"id":3,"menuName":"cloths","code":"hfuiu"},
{"id":4,"menuName":"Geoffrey","code":pr"}]
```

controller--

```
public function log()
    {
        $menuPermissions = MenuPermission::all();
        return view('master.dashboard',compact('menuPermissions'));
    }
```

How do I Show only the menuNames in a list?

the table looks like this
[image: menu-permissions table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I guess you are using Laravel Blade, if that's the case you can use below code**

```
@foreach($menuPermissions as $menuPermission)   
   @foreach(json_decode($menuPermission->menuids) as $ids)   
      {{$ids->menuName}}
   @endforeach 

@endforeach
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check now

Comment: do you mean menuIds Table ?

Comment: No. Table name is "menu-permissions". there is a field called "menuIds" which look like that

Comment: simple you just chnage filed name as shown above like $menuPermission->menuIds

Comment: But then I get the whole array. I just want the "menuName"

Comment: oh okhay can you show me menuPermissions data

Comment: ive updated the answer check it out

Comment: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given

now showing this